# Is it bad to take HttpRequest and HttpRespone to the implementation level in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I heard that taking the HttpRequest and HttpRespone from controller to implementation level is no good for the Security level.. is that true.. and if so how to avoid it... please do advice..

Thank you in advance..

Comment: Never allow anything else than stuff that relies on your web (like controllers, views) access the request/response... Its not about security it is about design and you don't want (or should) tie your whole application to the web layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***HttpServletRequest*** should not be passed to the service layer.

If you need the request explicitly you can place the logic in the web layer. Or extend the library and allow it to take a Map of parameters (if possible) and you can also

Wrap the **HttpRequest** and **HttpResponse** in your classes implementing interfaces and make the service layer rely on the interfaces.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Sasa.D...Even i am thinking on that way.. do me 1 more favor sir can you give the any example for that so i can understand in more depth...Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The main aim of Service layer is reusability and [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) i.e., the service layer should be able process the business logic from various sources like web tier `controllers` or other web services (i.e., different end points).

So, if your webtier objects (`FormBean` objects, `httprequest`, `httpsession` objects, etc..) are scattered into the service layer then there is a tight coupling between the services and with the `controller` layer. If you wanted to expose or reuse the same service for other end points or channels, then you will end up in making changes (removing webtier objects or placing if else conditions in the code) to the service layer (to support different end systems), which is not good.

In n-tier (or 3-tier) architecture, service layer (along with DAOs) should only use domain/entity objects and should not be mixed with front end (web tier) objects. Otherwise, the application can't be supportable/extended easily to multiple endpoints.

Comment: That was great explanation sir.. but please provide me with an example to understand in deeper..so i can enhance my knowledge..Thankyou sir

Answer (score 0):

Your application should be designed in such a way the component responsible for a task should do the required job and delegate the piece of objects/variables to the next set of methods/classes. It would be better to extract the Header/Body/Attachments from the HTTP Request/Response and send it accordingly to business class for further processing.